# Debugging malicious program

Tags: debugging, ida

I have a malicious .scr file which i heard steals your gaming account items. Is there a way to debug this .scr file in safe environment without executing it. I opened it in IDA PRO but did not find it much useful.

Any pointers regarding the debugging process will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analysis of malware is risky. If you are committed you at least need a Linux host with Windows guest on a sacrificial computer that doesn't have a wireless card and is unplugged from internet. Malware often has a mechanism to detect the jail. Common VMs use standard drivers and checking if running in jail is easy. If in jail then do nothing is a one line of code. To make matters worse,  decent malware often has a mechanism to jailbreak from a VM and infect host Windows. Don't even mention Sandboxie. Last, but not least - some malware starts revenging if you try to decompile it. So, instead of just a stolen game password you might have a big mess.
So, if you have a sacrificial computer and free time, then go ahead. But do it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

First: DEBUG a program means that you execute it, so if you know that the program is a malware you should do it in a safe enviroment like a virtual machine. 
Malware usually use to protect themselves from debuggers, so this kind of job needs so many skills.

A kind of analysis that you can do is to execute the malware in a virtual machine and take a snapshot of the machine, then analyze the dump with Volatily and see what connections have been made by the system, the state of process etc..

Comment: At one point, hostile code broke out of my VMWare with windows guest/windows host using some `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` trickery. It then spread over network and things got messy. It was easier to replace the whole ecosystem.